# Unknown status bar icon - Galaxy note 9

Tags: notification-icons, samsung-galaxy-note-9

Today I (very briefly) spotted a new icon in my status bar.
It looked like a little person icon (head and shoulder, silhouette kind of thing) with sound waves on the right (like WiFi signal but horizontal).

It was only there for a second so I wasn't able to get a screenshot but will definitely try if i see it again.

I haven't come across this icon in the 8 or so years that I've been using android and I can't think of any obvious app that it would be for.
I haven't installed any apps in the last week or so either.

If it helps, I was on my Galaxy Note 9 on Oreo (8.1.0 / Samsung Experience 9.5), it is rooted (Magisk) and has Xposed installed.

Any help identifying this icon is greatly appreciated and I'll update if I manage to get a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This icon indicates that Google is sharing location.

The same icon can be seen in Google Maps by accessing the navigation drawer and the menu "Location Sharing".

Source: [AndroidCentral Forum - Person icon in notification bar that quickly disappears](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/933782-person-icon-notification-bar-quickly-disappears.html)

Answer (score 1):

As per my findings, thanks to @Firelord, this icon is used for voice-over.

[image]

There may be multiple apps that use this icon but it seems the most common would be Google Voice (which I don't have).